# Why is the height rendered differently for these spans?

Tags: html, css, safari

I noticed the height of spans is rendered differently depending on the font-family selected and the parent object.  For example, with font-size: 14px, and font-family: Helvetica or Arial, the span has height 17px within a `button` but 16px within an `a`.  With Verdana the height is 17px for both spans.

Here's an example:

```css
div.arial {
  font-family: Arial;
}
div.helvetica {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
div.verdana { 
  font-family: Verdana;
}
button,
a  {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
button {
  background: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="arial">
  <button>
    <span>arial button 17px</span>
  </button>
  <a href="#">
    <span>arial anchor 16px?</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="helvetica">
  <button>
    <span>helvetica button 17px</span>
  </button>
  <a href="#">
    <span>helvetica anchor 16px?</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="verdana">
  <button>
    <span>verdana button 17px</span>
  </button>
  <a href="#">
    <span>verdana anchor 17px</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Why is this happening?  Is there some work-around possible?

Comment: The difference is basically due to different fonts used. *Is there some work-around possible?* - what kind of work-around. Can you explain me?

Comment: The difference is not between the fonts, but between being wrapped by a button and wrapped by an anchor.  In the example, a span with Helvetica wrapped in a button has a different height than a span with Helvetica wrapped in an anchor.

Comment: When i checked in `inspect element` tab, only the last (verdana font) two elements showed a difference.

Comment: @rv7 - Which browser/OS are you using?  The heights I used above are what shows up for me on Chrome and Safari on MacOS.

Comment: I am using Chrome 69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `display: inline-block` and the height on both the `button` and `a` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the user agent stylesheet is overriding the font for span wrapped by button. Try adding the font-family:inherit for button css.

```
button {
  background: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-family:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The work-around would be setting the `a` or the `span` tag to have `line-height: 16px;`.